# Heroku python deploy error

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

When I start my simple python app I get this error

```
web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web.1  |     import module_att_extractor_from_desc as module_desc_extractor
```

Unfortunately it is not very clear... I can't understand exactly where is the error on my module...
How can I get more info about the error?

Another thing how can I see all the print that I do in the terminal?

Comment: How you are displaying the messages?

Answer (score 0):

to look up the logs:

For heroku you should use an app or a add-ons like:

[Logentries](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries)
and
[Papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail)